# Convert visible cells in a range to merged cells with possible With Statement. Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range, with-statement

Is there a way I can make a with statement with the following?

```
If ActiveSheet.Range("B17").EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
    If Range("C17").Value = "" Then
        With Range("C17:E17")
            .Locked = False
            .Merge
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
        With Range("F17:G17")
            .Locked = False
            .Merge
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
        With Range("H17:J17")
            .Locked = False
            .Merge
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
    End If
End If
If ActiveSheet.Range("B18").EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
    If Range("C18").Value = "" Then
        With Range("C18:E18")
            .Locked = False
            .Merge
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
        With Range("F18:G18")
            .Locked = False
            .Merge
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
        With Range("H18:J18")
            .Locked = False
            .Merge
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
    End If
End If
```

The range on the worksheet goes from B17 - B31 and the above code is the same for the entire range.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
dim i as int

for i= 17 to 31
  If ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
    If Range("C" & i).Value = "" Then
        With Range("C" & i & ":E" & i)
            .Locked = False
            .Merge
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
        With Range("F" & i & ":G" & i)
            .Locked = False
            .Merge
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
        With Range("H" & i & ":J" & i)
            .Locked = False
            .Merge
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
    End If
  End If
next i
```

(you could do another nested for loop for the columns to merge to make it more efficient, but with only 3 blocks it isn't too annoying just to leave them as you've got them)